# How can i share my app url on fb?

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code from where I am redirecting to facebook-

```
(void)fb_BtnPressed:(UIButton*)button
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/"]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use social framework provided in iOS for this purpose, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/composeViewControllerForServiceType:) you can find more about it

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *vc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [vc setInitialText:@"Your URL"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or your can use deep linking
Here is a blog which will guide you through, what is deep linking and how to implement it in our app.

http://www.icoders.in/deep-linking-in-ios/

In you appdelegate.m, add this method.

```html
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

    NSString *path = [url path];
    NSString *query = [url query];
    if ([query isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homepage"];
        vc1 = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstStoryboard"];
        self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
        [self.navController pushViewController:vc1 animated:NO];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    }
    return YES;
    
}
```

You can use the url to get to a specified page (view controller) in your app.
After adding a url scheme, you can run your app in the simulator's browser using the following syntax,

"application-name://"

application-name as specified in the url scheme.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this in one of my app. Use the below mentioned code:

```
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

//to add a link to your fb post which will display as per the metadata of your url
[mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sampleurl.com"]];

//this will just display a plain text of fb post
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"http://www.sampleurl.com"];

[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    switch (result) {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;

        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}];

[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add Social.framework.

Than add `#import <Social/Social.h>` in to your file.

And add below code to open SLComposeViewController:

```
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"<YOUR APP URL>"];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also you get a completion block like:

```
[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Successfully shared on your wall");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```